# Objective C: Change Line Width Using UISlider

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, core-graphics

I have this code to change the stroke width of the line i'm using to draw on the screen.

```
- (IBAction)changeSize:(id)sender
{
    if (Slider.value > 25.0)
    {
        Width += 3;
    }
}
```

It's working but when i drag the slider thumb straight to the maximum it just adds a little size only but when i do it partly it's getting bigger each step.

Also, when i decrease it on the UISlider it still adds more... it's not decreasing...

How can i do resizing using UISlider??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are telling it to increase the width by 3 when the slider is changed.

You would need to **set the width equal to the slider value**.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to understand how sliders work. The Slider.value is your current slider value and it goes from Slider.minimumValue to Slider.maximumValue, witch you can set when creating the slider. You should set those to your minimum line stroke and to maximum line stroke.
In your changeSize method you should then only have 1 line: Width = Slider.value; What you are doing now, is that each time you move the slider and its value is larger then 25.0, you increase the stroke by 3.
As for the speed of slider movement effecting the stroke in your case: How many times the method changeSize will be called is time based, not value. So if you slide it faster, it will be called lesser times then if you slide it slowly, therefor increasing your Width lesser times by 3.